# Remove empty string keys from nested dictionary, dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

This works:

```
def delete_empty_keys(d):

    new_d = {}
    for key,value in d.items():
        if key != '' and not isinstance(value, dict):
            new_d[key] = value
        elif key != '' and isinstance(value, dict):
            new_d[key] = delete_empty_keys(value)
        else:
            pass
    return new_d
```

How do I turn it into a dict comprehension? I've tried this but I can't get it to work, I should have an `else pass` at the end.

```
def delete_empty_keys(d):
    return {key: value
    if key != '' and not isinstance(value, dict)
    else delete_empty_keys(value)
    if key != '' and isinstance(value, dict)
    #else pass??
    for key, value in d.items()
    }
```

Comment: Samle input and expected output please

Comment: Note: you are not filtering `None` keys, you are filtering empty strings.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop

```
for key,value in d.items():
    if key != '' and not isinstance(value, dict):
        new_d[key] = value
    elif key != '' and isinstance(value, dict):
        new_d[key] = delete_empty_keys(value)
    else:
        pass
```

is really just testing if the key should be skipped, *or* if it isn't, how to handle the value. If you pull out the key test to a separate `if` statement, it can be rewritten as

```
for key, value in d.items():
    if key != '':
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            new_d[key] = value
        else:
            new_d[key] = delete_empty_keys(value)
```

So the `if key != '':` test is really *filtering* the items, selecting which should be part of the new dictionary. Filtering in comprehensions is done with extra `if` components in the loop:

```
<item> for <target> in <iterable> if <test>  # optional: more for loops and if tests
```

The `if <test>` part filters the iterable, limiting what items are used. Use the same in a dictionary comprehension.

This leaves the inner `if...else` test, which can be expressed with a conditional expression (picking between two options):

```
# iteration, for <target> in <iterable>
for key, value in d.items():
    # filter, if <test>
    if key != '':
        # <item>, here a <key> and <value> expression for the dict comprehension
        new_d[key] = value if not isinstance(value, dict) else delete_empty_keys(value)
```

Now you have a form that can be turned into a dictionary comprehension:

```
{
    key: value if not isinstance(value, dict) else delete_empty_keys(value)
    for key, value in d.items()
    if key != ''
}
```

or, in your function:

```
def delete_empty_keys(d):
    return {key: value if not isinstance(value, dict) else delete_empty_keys(value)
            for key, value in d.items() if key != ''}
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that while this works, it may not be preferred - a complex comprehension is often less readable than a for loop with conditions. Excellent answer nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, just realised when I wrote it! Thank you sir!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: that didn't need adding to my answer, however.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you *really* want to do this:

```
def delete_empty_keys(d):
    return {k: delete_empty_keys(v) if isinstance(v, dict) 
            else v 
            for k, v in d.items() if k != ''}
```

Example:

```
d = {'': 'delete_me',
     'a': {'': {'delete': 'me',
                'me': 'too'},
           'dont': 'delete_me',
           'keep': 'me'},
     'b': {'': 'bye'},
     'c': 'not_nested'}

delete_empty_keys(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'dont': 'delete_me', 'keep': 'me'}, 'b': {}, 'c': 'not_nested'}
```

You do not `pass` in `dict` comprehensions, because `pass` doesn't return anything. Everything in a comprehension should return something.

Also, as noted in a comment: `None != ''`.